# Getting a viewstate error on button click on Aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, button, controls, html

I have a web page in **Asp.Net** and a button on it

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRecordHours" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:VolunteerDashboard,btnRecordHours%>"
CssClass="buttonGreen buttonWidth" OnClick="btnRecordHours_Click" />
```

With this on its `OnClick` event i have attached a method named `btnRecordHours_Click`

```
protected void btnRecordHours_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Some Code
}
```

But when i am clicking this button i am getting following error:

> Failed to load viewstate.
>   The control tree into which viewstate is 
>   being loaded must match the control tree 
>   that was used to save viewstate during the previous request. 
>   For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

It is not even able to hit the `Click` event on post back directly showing this error `OnClick`.

`Hyperlink` and some other button are working fine on this page but this issue persist for some of the button.

Comment: Are you adding any controls to the page dynamically in either `Page_Load` or `Page_PreRender`?

Comment: No, we are not adding control dynamically in either Page_Load or Page_PreRender

Comment: Are you using jQuery to change any (even hiddenfields) values on the form?

Comment: [I answered a similar question some time ago][1]
Perhaps this will help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067024/failed-to-load-viewstate/6155989#6155989

Good luck
Harv

Comment: Yes on the page i am having many hidden field whose value i am changing using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I believe the issue you are having has to do with the fact that you have `asp:hiddenfields` and changing the value.

Try using normal html hidden fields and getting the value in the code behind using `Request.Form["nameofhiddenfield"]`.

Please note that you need the NAME of the hidden field, not the ID.

Comment: What can be the possible issue with hidden fields... I am using the same on many other pages but none of them is having this kind of issue.... Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to say...

Comment: When you use asp:hiddenfield it is a server control.  .NET viewstate contains the state of these controls and when the state of those controls change via a .NET method, it sees that as a potential hacker and gives you the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any update panels?  Because sometimes these issues come with using them, especially if multiple update panels are involved.